# Gerar XML com base no XSD

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2013, xsd

recebi aqui uns arquivos XSD para usar em uma aplicação que desenvolvi... gostaria de saber como faço para gerar uns XML de exemplo no Visual Studio para poder me situar na exportação dos dados. Quando tento fazer via Visual Studio em Generated XML example, dá uma mensagem de erro "...namespace was not resolved".

Segue exemplo de uns do XSD.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:cadastroDomiciliar="http://esus.ufsc.br/v2000/cadastrodomiciliar" xmlns:condicaoMoradia="http://esus.ufsc.br/v2000/condicaomoradia" xmlns:enderecoLocalPermanencia="http://esus.ufsc.br/v2000/enderecolocalpermanencia" xmlns:familiaRow="http://esus.ufsc.br/v2000/familiarow" xmlns:headerCdsCadastro="http://esus.ufsc.br/v2000/headercdscadastro" targetNamespace="http://esus.ufsc.br/v2000/cadastrodomiciliar" version="1.0">

  <xs:import namespace="http://esus.ufsc.br/v2000/headercdscadastro" schemaLocation="v2000headercdscadastro.xsd"/>

  <xs:import namespace="http://esus.ufsc.br/v2000/enderecolocalpermanencia" schemaLocation="v2000enderecolocalpermanencia.xsd"/>

  <xs:import namespace="http://esus.ufsc.br/v2000/condicaomoradia" schemaLocation="v2000condicaomoradia.xsd"/>

  <xs:import namespace="http://esus.ufsc.br/v2000/familiarow" schemaLocation="v2000familiarow.xsd"/>

  <xs:element name="cadastroDomiciliarTransport" type="cadastroDomiciliar:cadastroDomiciliarTransport"/>

  <xs:complexType name="cadastroDomiciliarTransport">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="dadosGerais" type="headerCdsCadastro:headerCdsCadastroTransport"/>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="enderecoLocalPermanencia" type="enderecoLocalPermanencia:enderecoLocalPermanenciaTransport"/>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="condicaoMoradia" type="condicaoMoradia:condicaoMoradiaTransport"/>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="stAnimaisNoDomicilio" type="xs:boolean"/>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="animaisNoDomicilio" type="xs:long"/>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="quantosAnimaisNoDomicilio" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="familias" type="familiaRow:familiaRowTransport"/>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="tpCdsOrigem" type="xs:int"/>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="1" name="uuid" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="1" name="uuidFichaOriginadora" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="fichaAtualizada" type="xs:boolean"/>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="statusTermoRecusaCadastroDomiciliarAtencaoBasica" type="xs:boolean"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

primeiro passo, coloque todos os seus `xsd` no mesmo local, aqui vamos chamar de:

```
Arquivo01.xsd // Não possui referencias
Arquivo02.xsd // Possui referencia a um tipo declarado no arquivo 01
Arquivo03.xsd // Possui referencia a um tipo declarado no arquivo 01
Arquivo04.xsd // Possui referencia a um tipo declarado no arquivo 02
```

Então abra o `Visual Studio Command Propmt` e execute o seguinte comando.

```
xsd.exe Arquivo01.xsd Arquivo02.xsd Arquivo03.xsd Arquivo04.xsd /class
```

Note que a ordem que você declara os `*.XSD` é importante, por exemplo, se você coloca-se o `Arquivo02.xsd` antes do `Arquivo01.xsd`, como o arquivo `Arquivo02.xsd` possui uma depedencia com `Arquivo01.xsd`, o comando iria disparar uma exceção.

Porém se inverter a ordem do `Arquivo02.xsd` com o `Arquivo03.xsd`, não terá problemas, afinal ambos não dependem do outro.

Agora tendo como base o seu arquivo sem algumas propriedades (afinal não sei qual é a estrutura dos seus imports).

**arquivo.xsd**

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:cadastroDomiciliar="http://esus.ufsc.br/v2000/cadastrodomiciliar" xmlns:condicaoMoradia="http://esus.ufsc.br/v2000/condicaomoradia" xmlns:enderecoLocalPermanencia="http://esus.ufsc.br/v2000/enderecolocalpermanencia" xmlns:familiaRow="http://esus.ufsc.br/v2000/familiarow" xmlns:headerCdsCadastro="http://esus.ufsc.br/v2000/headercdscadastro" targetNamespace="http://esus.ufsc.br/v2000/cadastrodomiciliar" version="1.0">      
  <xs:element name="cadastroDomiciliarTransport" type="cadastroDomiciliar:cadastroDomiciliarTransport"/>
  <xs:complexType name="cadastroDomiciliarTransport">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="stAnimaisNoDomicilio" type="xs:boolean"/>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="animaisNoDomicilio" type="xs:long"/>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="quantosAnimaisNoDomicilio" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="tpCdsOrigem" type="xs:int"/>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="1" name="uuid" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="1" name="uuidFichaOriginadora" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="fichaAtualizada" type="xs:boolean"/>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="statusTermoRecusaCadastroDomiciliarAtencaoBasica" type="xs:boolean"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

então ao executar o seguinte comando:

```
xsd.exe arquivo.xsd /class
```

será gerado o seguinte arquivo:

**arquivo.cs**

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.42000
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using System.Xml.Serialization;

// 
// This source code was auto-generated by xsd, Version=4.0.30319.1.
// 


/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://esus.ufsc.br/v2000/cadastrodomiciliar")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="http://esus.ufsc.br/v2000/cadastrodomiciliar", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class cadastroDomiciliarTransport {

    private bool stAnimaisNoDomicilioField;

    private bool stAnimaisNoDomicilioFieldSpecified;

    private long[] animaisNoDomicilioField;

    private string quantosAnimaisNoDomicilioField;

    private int tpCdsOrigemField;

    private bool tpCdsOrigemFieldSpecified;

    private string uuidField;

    private string uuidFichaOriginadoraField;

    private bool fichaAtualizadaField;

    private bool fichaAtualizadaFieldSpecified;

    private bool statusTermoRecusaCadastroDomiciliarAtencaoBasicaField;

    private bool statusTermoRecusaCadastroDomiciliarAtencaoBasicaFieldSpecified;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public bool stAnimaisNoDomicilio {
        get {
            return this.stAnimaisNoDomicilioField;
        }
        set {
            this.stAnimaisNoDomicilioField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool stAnimaisNoDomicilioSpecified {
        get {
            return this.stAnimaisNoDomicilioFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.stAnimaisNoDomicilioFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("animaisNoDomicilio", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public long[] animaisNoDomicilio {
        get {
            return this.animaisNoDomicilioField;
        }
        set {
            this.animaisNoDomicilioField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string quantosAnimaisNoDomicilio {
        get {
            return this.quantosAnimaisNoDomicilioField;
        }
        set {
            this.quantosAnimaisNoDomicilioField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public int tpCdsOrigem {
        get {
            return this.tpCdsOrigemField;
        }
        set {
            this.tpCdsOrigemField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool tpCdsOrigemSpecified {
        get {
            return this.tpCdsOrigemFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.tpCdsOrigemFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string uuid {
        get {
            return this.uuidField;
        }
        set {
            this.uuidField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string uuidFichaOriginadora {
        get {
            return this.uuidFichaOriginadoraField;
        }
        set {
            this.uuidFichaOriginadoraField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public bool fichaAtualizada {
        get {
            return this.fichaAtualizadaField;
        }
        set {
            this.fichaAtualizadaField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool fichaAtualizadaSpecified {
        get {
            return this.fichaAtualizadaFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.fichaAtualizadaFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public bool statusTermoRecusaCadastroDomiciliarAtencaoBasica {
        get {
            return this.statusTermoRecusaCadastroDomiciliarAtencaoBasicaField;
        }
        set {
            this.statusTermoRecusaCadastroDomiciliarAtencaoBasicaField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool statusTermoRecusaCadastroDomiciliarAtencaoBasicaSpecified {
        get {
            return this.statusTermoRecusaCadastroDomiciliarAtencaoBasicaFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.statusTermoRecusaCadastroDomiciliarAtencaoBasicaFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }
}
```

agora para criar o seu arquivo xml, use o seguinte codigo:

```
var cadastro = new cadastroDomiciliarTransport();
/* preencha o seu objeto */

var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(cadastroDomiciliarTransport));
using(var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
{
    using(var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter))
    {
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, cadastro);
        var xml = stringWriter.ToString(); // Your XML
    }
}
```

No exemplo acima usei um `StringWriter`, caso queira escrever um arquivo, use o `FileStream` e um `StreamWriter`.

Comment: Tenho que olha a data da pergunta antes de publica uma resposta,

Answer (score 0):

Se o xsd for válido, basta abri-lo no Visual Studio. Uma janela Xml Schema Explorer irá aparecer, ai é só clicar em um dos elementos da raiz com o botão direito e selecionar a opção Generate Sample XML.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]